# creating empty 3 channeled image and add pixel values

Tags: python, opencv, heatmap

I am trying to create empty image, with 3 channels:

```
heatmap  = np.zeros_like((416,416,3))
```

Now i want it to act as pseudo heatmap, so i created a box

```
box = [0,0,25,25]
```

And now increase value of pixels in this box in the empty image by 1

```
while( box[0] < box[2]):
    y_axis = int(box[1])
    while(y_axis < box[3]):
            heatmap[box[0]][y_axis] += 1
            y_axis  = y_axis+1
    box[0] = box[0]+1
```

Using this i get colors but "full"colors, i would need transparent color so i can put this "pseudo heatmap" over image.

How can i acieve this?

Comment: three channels and "I want transparency" does not bode well for your wants. Normally you have 3 channels (BGR, RGB, HVS, etc) and a Transparency value == 4 channels. Transparent =255 is opaque, 0 is translucent, something in between is transparent

Comment: How do you convert this array to an image to overlay elsewhere? Does that overlay function provide transparency? Maybe you must add a 4th channel: alpha.

Comment: I have solved the transparency using cv2.addWeighted(heatmap , alpha, img, 1 - alpha, 0, output), however another question has occured, i will create another topic for the question not to OT. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To create a transparent image you need a 4 channel image, 4th channel is representing the alpha channel. To create a transparent image, you can ignore the RGB values and directly set the alpha channel to be 0. 
So you can use this:

```
heatmap  = np.zeros_like((416,416,4),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: I have solved the transparency using cv2.addWeighted(heatmap , alpha, img, 1 - alpha, 0, output), however another question has occured, i will create another topic for the question not to OT. thanks.